# How to get my reset button to save the current date to my function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a countup timer that will display the number of days since a particular event occurred. Some people here have helped me with my reset button on my script but I cannot get my script to use the current date after the reset button has been pressed. Currently my reset button will reset the timer but as soon as I refresh the page it reverts to the original date that was entered into my script.

```
 var timeToCountUpFrom = "Jul 8, 2019 12:00:00"
        window.onload = function() {
        // Month Day, Year Hour:Minute:Second, id-of-element-container
        countUpFromTime(timeToCountUpFrom, 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
        document.getElementById('reset-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
          timeToCountUpFrom = new Date()
          countUpFromTime(timeToCountUpFrom, 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
        })
       };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it use the time from when the user last clicked the reset button, you'll need to store that data somewhere like `localStorage`. You could do

```
var saved = window.localStorage.getItem('timeToCountUpFrom');
var timeToCountUpFrom = saved ? new Date(JSON.parse(saved)) : new Date(); //defaults it to a new Date() if there is no saved value
```

And then your reset button would:

```
document.getElementById('reset-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  timeToCountUpFrom = new Date();
  window.localStorage.setItem(
    'timeToCountUpFrom', 
    JSON.stringify(timeToCountUpFrom)
  );

  countUpFromTime(timeToCountUpFrom, 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it now changes to a new date every time I reload the page. I think I'm missing something. Do I have to create the file for this to save to? This is my first Javascript project so i'm pretty new to this. Thank you. @Anthony

Comment: You will need to click the reset button at least one time for it to save, and then every reload of the page after that should use the time you clicked the reset button

Comment: I have clicked the reset button and when I reload the page it just starts back at 0.

Comment: @RyanM take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jbvps9fg/1/ Once you have clicked the Reset button, you can Run the fiddle or reload the page and you will see the displayed date will not change.

Comment: Awesome! I had something in my script that wasn't necessary. Thank you for your the help.